# ASP.NET MVC - map bools in View to List of ints in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

We have a system for managing various aspects of construction Tradesmen in the UK.

We’re adding a new section to manage their Accreditations and would like to simplify our current implementation.

We want to have a `List<int>` in our ViewModel, but aren't sure how we write to this from our View.  See questions in the pseudo View code below:

We're using Kendo if it helps things.

**ViewModel**

AccreditationApprovalViewModel.cs

```
public class AccreditationApprovalViewModel : ApprovalViewModel
{
    // currently have:
    // public bool HasAccreditation1;
    // public bool HasAccreditation2;
    // …
    // public bool HasAccreditationN;

    // We want to change the individual bools above to:
    [DisplayName(“Has Accreditation“)]
    public List<int> HasAccreditations;
}
```

**View**

AccreditationApproval.cshtml

Have a number of boolean flag controls in here:

- Accreditation1Flag

  - if set to true, int 1 is added to HasAccreditations list in ViewModel (if not already in list)
  - if set to false, int 1 is removed from HasAccreditations list in ViewModel
- Accreditation2Flag

  - if set to true, int 2 is added to HasAccreditations list in ViewModel (if not already in list)
  - if set to false, int 2 is removed from HasAccreditations list in ViewModel

Similar for Accreditations 3, 4, 5 etc

***Our two questions are:***

- how do we create the EditorFor entry, to allow it to write to the `List<int>` in the ViewModel
- how do we concatenate a number to the DisplayString in the LabelFor?

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.HasAccreditations.Concat(" 1"))
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HasAccreditations[0]) @* bool control writing to int in array *@    

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.HasAccreditations.Concat(" 2"))
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HasAccreditations[1]) @* bool control writing to int in array *@
```

Comment: What is your actual question? I don't see it in here. If you have many accreditations, I would not store them in individual `bool`s. Give each one an ID in a lookup table and create a many to many join.

Comment: Jonathan, I've modified my post to be clearer about my question. We currently store our Accreditations in individual `bool`s, but want them to be in a List instead. We're not sure what would go in our View

Answer (score 0):

I think you should restructure your model, otherwise you will be forever translating back and forth, you won't easily be able to add new accreditation types, etc.

One table for person. A many to many intermediary table with person id and accreditation id. And a new table for accreditation with accreditation id and accreditation title.

If you use entity framework or similar, a properly joined table will expose all the related properties easily for the purpose of building up your model / view model.

For your view, of you are using kendo, you could use their multipicker, or a series of check boxes with accreditation id as the value and accreditation title as the label.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Jonathan.   If we got to rewrite this, we'd definitely restructure the model as you suggested, but we don't have the resources to do that on this version.    For this version, we just hoped we could possibly write some javascript that would do a conversion from individual bools into an int collection.